# I need to copy a row and paste it into worksheet 15x while changing the date

Tags: excel, vba

I receive a report in excel that has over 200 rows.  Each row needs 15 rows added with the same information but with a different date starting two weeks in the future.  There are six columns (two are blank).

IZU072E11NN1DTT "" EA 12/3/2012 "" 1.5

This is currently being done manually. I want to create a macro but am unsure how to do the loop and change the date.

Comment: Changing the date would be just setting the cell value to whatever date you have calculated, e.g. `Cells(10,"X").Value = myDate`.  The loop would be just writing code such as `For i = 1 To 15` `...` `Next`.

Comment: For each of the 15 rows the date will increase by one week. The date part is the part that is really hanging me up.

Comment: `myDate = myDate + 7` will increase the date variable by one week.  (7 days = 1 week is the current exchange rate.)